# How to set a trigger to insert in another table from another schema?

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

**How to set a trigger to insert in another table from another schema ?**

---

**Brief explanation**

Considering schema "S" and schemas "1" to "n". 
Consider that Schema "S" has table Users and table Company.
The table users has a relationship 1:1 to table Company. Every User is in a company. The table Company has the column "schema" (varchar(255))

Schema "S" has the table Users and table Company defined. Every other schema should have acopy of table Users.

However the table Users is only modified on schema S.

**Everytime table Users in Schema "S" is modified, I want to replicate the changes to the schema 'n' IF and only IF the column "schema" in table "Company" == 'n'.**

*This restriction makes this question different from the other questions!*

Ah yes:

- All the schemas remains on the same database.

[image: Illustration of the issue]

**Example**

Consider the Table Users has the following columns:

- Id - int
- username - Varchar(255)
- dateBirth - Date
- idCompany  - FK int

Consider the table Company has the following columns:

- Id - int
- schema  - Varchar(255)

When I make an insert on the Users table on schema "S", I want the following to happen:

```
    if User.Company.schema == "schema A"{

        replicate to schema "A";

    } else if User.Company.schema == "schema N"{
        replicate to schema "N";
    }
....
```

Im confused on how to do that logic in the code below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `user_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

END
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're replicating this data rather than, say, creating a filtered view of the original table?

Comment: Hmm, no reason, I just dont know filtered views. Ah wait, There is a reason. Actually its because of Hibernate. https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-persist-an-entity-that-has-a-relationship-with-another-entity-from-another-schema/2691

Comment: Does anything attempt to modify the derived tables (Company A...D), or are they read-only?

Comment: read-only. But Hibernate has to map it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic SQL to build an `INSERT` query to the other database:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `user_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `user` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SELECT schema INTO @schema FROM Company WHERE Id = NEW.idCompany;
  SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `', @schema, '`.`Users` (id, username, dateBirth, idCompany) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)';
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  SET @id = NEW.id;
  SET @username = NEW.username;
  SET @dateBirth = NEW.dateBirth;
  SET @idCompany = NEW.idCompany;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @id, @username, @dateBirth, @idCompany;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Can I use the same for after_update and after_delete ?

Comment: @KenobiShan obviously you will have to change the query you prepare, but the basic concept should still work.

Comment: Is it okay if i ask you a favor? the schema column, actually is an FK. I will edit my question. If you can just help me with that, i would GREATLY GREATLY appreciate it haha

Comment: @KenobiShan it depends on how different you are making the question. If it's a lot, you should probably ask a new one.

Comment: Actually, its just that. The users table has a FK to Company table. The company table has the schema column.

Comment: I hadnt noticed it. Because I was too worried trying to make the problem simpler to post it. its okay if you cant.

Comment: So what do you want to do to the Company table?

Comment: I just want to get the @schema name from that FK. Thats all;.

Comment: @KenobiShan it's late. I'll take a look in the morning. But when you do the insert to the main `Users` table, is the `company` FK the same value as should be inserted into the other schema?

Comment: The company table shouldnt be inserted in the other schema. It just points to a table which has the information to which schema it should be copied to.

Comment: You should just be able to set a variable to the result of `SELECT schema FROM Company WHERE id = NEW.idCompany`, and use that in place of this answer's uses of `NEW.schema`.

Comment: @Uueerdo indeed I think that is correct based on my understanding of the problem.

Comment: @KenobiShan see my edit. If I understand your problem correctly, that should do what you want.

Comment: Select is no valid at this position for this server version, expecting "(", WITH

Comment: @KenobiShan have you changed your DBMS? Why is it suddenly not working?

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing of Hybernate, but given that you only want these tables to be read-only, views may work. Try something like the following (some names have been fudged due to lack of detail in the question) in lieu of your CREATE TABLE statements for the Company tables.

```
CREATE VIEW users AS
SELECT `id`, `username`, `dateBirth`, `schema`
FROM S.users
WHERE `schema` = 'schema X';
```

If this works, it saves all the overhead of replication.